# Desempenho de Consulta em MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, desempenho

Tenho no meu formulário a opção de realizar uma busca por Rg ou Cpf. Então me veio a dúvida sobre desempenho da consulta usando o seguinte código:

```
SELECT * FROM DADOSPESSOAIS WHERE (Rg = @Rg OR Cpf = @Cpf);
```

Esse código acima "custa" mais do que se eu fizesse duas consultas, ou seja, fizesse uma consulta para Rg e caso me retornasse null eu fizesse outra para Cpf ?

```
SELECT * FROM DADOSPESSOAIS WHERE (Rg = @Rg);

SELECT * FROM DADOSPESSOAIS WHERE (Cpf = @Cpf);
```

Comment: Qual é a duvida entao?

Comment: Depende do uso e do contexto, existem outros fatores também como o uso de índices. Quem pode responder isso é o banco, use o comando `explain` para saber sobre o plano de execução da consulta.

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso acredito que 1 SELECT seja melhor que 2 SELECTs.

Mas o que realmente vai fazer diferença é a existência de um índice para o campo Rg e outro índice para o campo Cpf.

Answer (score 0):

A diferença em desempenho entre as duas queries são minimas, são coisa de milisegundos, mas você tem que ter em mente como a resposta acima disse "melhor uma queries do que duas", pois duas queries além de lhe trazer possivelmente dados redundantes para a sua view, também você teria que fazer todo um laço de interação entre elas até chegar o resultado pretendido, então seja qual for a forma que você esteja trabalhando em seu sistema, sempre que você for apresentar algum resultado na tela para os seus usuarios, tente sempre ter isso em 1 query (porém, sabemos que nem sempre é possível), procurando sempre usar as sintaxes nativas do seu BD para evitar o máximo possível que você tenha que fazer validações e derivados na parte do client, sempre procure já trazer os dados corretos do seu server e apenas ter a preocupação de mostra-los em seu client side.

Espero ter ajudado e agredado.

Até mais.